# In Node.js, does listening to an EventEmitter, create a reference to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, garbage-collection, eventemitter

If I have some code like this:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Bot extends EventEmitter {
  sendMessage() {
    // do something
    this.emit('messageSent', 'user123');
  }
}

class Controller {
  loadBot() {
    const bot = new Bot();
    bot.on('messageSent', userId => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

Would the `bot` object created inside `loadBot` be destroyed immediately? or perhaps later via garbage collection?

Or would the instance of `Controller` hold a reference to it so that `bot` would never be destroyed until the `Controller` instance was destroyed?

Comment: Where would a `Controller` instance hold a reference to `bot`? It's a local variable that goes out of scope when the method ends, not a property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Registering an event listener all by itself does not keep it from being garbage collected.  Something has to actually have a reference to the `Bot` object itself (so that events could actually be emitted from it) for it to not be garbage collected.

In  your Controller class, if nothing else has a reference to the `Bot` instance you create, then it will be eligible for garbage collection.  This makes sense because if nothing has a reference to it, then nothing else can use it and nothing can ever call its custom method `sendMessage()` either.

As you have your code now, your `bot` variable is just a local variable inside the `loadBot()` method and nothing else has a reference to it.  So, as soon as the `loadBot()` method is done executing, the `bot` variable will then be eligible for garbage collection because there is no code anywhere that could ever use or reach that object again.  That makes it eligible for garbage collection.

From your code, it looks like maybe you meant for the `bot` variable to be an instance variable of your `Controller` object.  If that was the case, then as long as some had a reference to your `Controller` object, then the `bot` object would stay alive too.

So, it looks like maybe you meant to do this:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Bot extends EventEmitter {
  sendMessage() {
    // do something
    this.emit('messageSent', 'user123');
  }
}

class Controller {
  loadBot() {
    this.bot = new Bot();
    this.bot.on('messageSent', userId => {
      // do something
    });
  }

  send() {
      this.bot.sendMessage();
  }
}

var c = new Controller();
c.loadBot();
```

Here you retain a reference to the `bot` variable in the instance data of the `Controller` object and thus it can be reached by other code (like the `send()` method) or any other code that accesses the `.bot` property on your `Controller` object.

Answer (score 0):

I DONOT think the object **bot** will be GCed, Because there is a listener hold a reference to it.

Comment: welcome to SO, James! As @guptron pointed out in the accepted answer, bot will be GCed as it only exists within the scope of the loadBot method of the Controller class. The event listener dies with the end of the method, as the instance of Bot initiated within it can't be accesed elsewhere.